# Is it possible to import a generic promise in typescript?

Tags: generics, typescript, promise, sequelize.js

I'd like to import PromiseT from sequelize.  I currently have this import statement:

```
import { sequelize, Instance, Model, DataTypes, Base } from './sequelize';
```

I found that this doesn't work:

```
let p: sequelize.PromiseT<MyModel[]>;
```

I can import the entire package:

```
import s = require('sequelize');
let p: s.PromiseT<UserInstance[]>;
```

Is there syntax to just import PromiseT?  Here is the relevant decls from sequelize.d.ts:

```
declare module "sequelize"
{
    ...
    module sequelize {
        ...
        interface PromiseT<T> extends Promise { ...  };
        ...
   }

    var sequelize: sequelize.SequelizeStatic;

    export = sequelize;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is not possible to _import_ something that is not _exported_. Unless the result of `var sequelize: sequelize.SequelizeStatic` contains some property that references `PromiseT`, you will not have access to it.

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot to check for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible - it works like any other type.  The above didn't work because it wasn't exported, as correctly indicated by sdgluck above.